# Titanium Appcelerator date format

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am using date picker in my application
When i click button it take selected date from date picker and set it to text field

```
 set.addEventListener('click',function(e){
      textfield.setValue(picker.value);
 });
```

It set date as `2016-02-29 18:30:00 +0000` but i want it as `29-02-2016`

How can i change date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one :

```
set.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  var selectedDate = new Date(e.value);
  textfield.setValue(selectedDate.getDate() +"-"+ selectedDate.getMonth() +"-"+ selectedDate.getFullYear());
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Momentjs`

```
var moment = require('alloy/moment');

set.addEventListener('click',function(e){
 textfield.setValue( moment(picker.value).format("DD-MM-YYYY") )
});
```

More details

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Alloy.builtins.moment

http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Thanks..i'll try this

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, you can use `var date = new Date(picker.value);` and then use the native [Javascript date functions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).

Comment: Yes..thanks for reply...i already done as u say and it works:)